# .net MVC identity ... getting data enter by a specific user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a class

```
public class Employee
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Designation { get; set; }
  public Guid UserId { get; set; }   
}
```

I have created different users and i am able to enter data by different users. On my controller i want to show the data only entered by logged user .. .here is my controller code

```
// GET: Employees
[Authorize]        
public ActionResult Index()
{
  MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true);
  var empList = from emp in db.Employees
                where emp.UserId == (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey
                select emp;
  return View(empList);         
}
```

I am getting error in my View of @foreach line

Here is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<LoginTestApp.Models.Employee>   
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2> 
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Designation)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
```

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Any help

Comment: can you show what are you doing in foreach loop?

Comment: I don't think the error is in the view, its more likely the query. Try materializing it with `.ToList()` and check. If your only returning one `Employee`, then why not return `.FirstOrDefault()` and make the model `@model LoginTestApp.Models.Employee` rather than `IEnumerable`? (the `foreach` loop is not necessary).

Comment: I agree with Stephen Muecke.

Comment: Why you are casting ProviderUserKey to GUID in the Query, as it is already GUID.?

Comment: @Ish, [From the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey(v=vs.110).aspx) `public virtual Object ProviderUserKey { get; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke and Sunil Rathod i want the list of employees added by a specific user thats why i am using IEnumerable....

Comment: @user3222601, If you want a collection in the view, that fine, but as I said above the error is probably in the query (not the view - the `foreach()` statement is just materializing the query). Just add `var test = empList.ToList();` after the query and debug it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke var test = empList.Tolist(); return null with var empList = from emp in db.Employees
                          where emp.UserId == (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey
                          select emp; but when i use var empList = from emp in db.Employees                                                   select emp; it return all list of employees .... but i want to get list of employees enter by logged user ...

Comment: So its maybe a problem with the `where` statement. Try commenting it out and see what that returns.

Comment: @StephenMuecke OR i am using totally wrong approach for this purpose???

Answer (score 0):

As Muecke suggests in the comments, you are currently returning an IQueriable instead of IEnumerable. So adding ToList() should solve this problem. You may also want to add a

```
return View(empList.ToList())
```

In addition, you may want to return the results sorted, by adding an order by to your query, or add it here:

```
return View(empList.SortBy(o=>o.Name).ToList())
```

Note also that it's confusing (as you can see in the comments) to have UserId be your indicator of who latest edited the record, especially on a table that contains people!

What I've found really helpful, is to base my models on an inherited class that contains everything I want to keep track of on the database level. For instance, you make a class called DataObject, that looks like this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public Guid CreatedByGuid { get; set; }
public Guid EditedByGuid { get; set; }
public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
public DateTime EditDateTime { get; set; }
```

Then, you can inherit these to your Employee class:

```
public class Employee: DataObject
{
```

Etc. Especially combined with Code First design, where the database is generated from your objects, this is really powerful and clean. You only have to add or change your DataObject class if you want to track anything else, and all classes and therefore tables will be updated.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer.... but i want to return list of employees enter by a specific user.... e.g. Mr. A & B has rights to enter employees name.. If user A logged on then only employees entered by him is visible :)

Comment: Yes, so created by the logged in user. So ... where emp.CreatedByGuid == (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey